# Create a multidimensional array from mysql recordset using nested foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, nested

Can someone please tell me which syntax to use to build the "directory" array from a mysql recordset? Thank you!

```
$directory = array();

foreach ($resultSetFromDB as $row){

    foreach ($row as $field => $value){

        $directory[$field][] = $value;

    }
}
```

I can print $field and $value, no problem

Comment: can we see the recordset?

Comment: add more description in your question. it is not clear what do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$directory = array();

foreach ($resultSetFromDB as $i => $row) {

    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {

        $directory[$i][$field] = $value;

    }
}
```